# Retrieving data from s3 bucket in pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I am reading data from s3 bucket in pyspark . I need to parallelize read operation and doing some transformation on the data. But its throwing error. Below is the code.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id=access_key,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)

prefix = 'clickEvent-2017-10-09'
files = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = prefix)
keys=[k.key for k in files]
pkeys = sc.parallelize(keys)
```

I have a global variable `d` which is an empty list. And I am appending `deviceId` data into this.

`applying flatMap on the keys`

```
pkeys.flatMap(map_func)
```

This the function

```
 def map_func(key):
   print "in map func"
   for line in key.get_contents_as_string().splitlines():
    # parse one line of json
     content = json.loads(line)
     d.append(content['deviceID'])
```

But the above code gives me error.
Can anyone help!

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues that I can see.  The first is you are trying to manually read data from S3 using boto instead of using the direct S3 support built into spark and hadoop.  It looks like you are trying to read text files containing json records per line.  If that is case, you can just do this in spark:

```
df = spark.read.json('s3://my-bucket/path/to/json/files/')
```

This will create a spark DataFrame for you by reading in the JSON data with each line as a row.  DataFrames require a rigid pre-defined schema (like a relational database table) which spark try to determine will determine by sampling some of your JSON data.  After you have the DataFrame all you need to do to get your column is select it like this:

```
df.select('deviceID')
```

The other issue worth pointing out is you are attempting to use a global variable to store data computed across your spark cluster.  It is possible to send data from your driver to all of the executors running on spark workers using either broadcast variables or implicit closures.  But there is no way in spark to write to a variable in your driver from an executor!  To transfer data from executors back to the driver you need to use spark's Action methods intended for exactly this purpose.

Actions are methods that tell spark you want a result computed so it needs to go execute the transformations you have told it about.  In your case you would probably either want to:

**If the results are large:** use DataFrame.write to save the results of your tranformations back to S3

**If the results are small:** DataFrame.collect() to download them back to your driver and do something with them

Comment: I am completely naive in this. So spare me !

Comment: My requirement is that I have multiple json files stored in s3 that have my clickstream data.(I have to go through 10  days data files ,where each day has multiple files). I need to read these files and store only those rows which satisfies some condition so need to read through all lines and do a check. If I parallelize read operation on keys then how would it be possible to collate results of all the files.

Comment: General workflow would be spark.read.json to load each event as a Row in a DataFrame.  Then you can use SQL like operations to manipulate the DataFrame.  In your case the filter method to select the Rows you care about.  Do whatever other transformations you need for your case then save the results somewhere using DF.write or collect.

Comment: I would recommend you read through the Spark documentation here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html

Comment: If I need to replicate this in Java . What should be the approach. Link to some source would be great help

Comment: The approach would be the same.  The same methods exist in the Java API.